# how can we avoid header and footer code repeating in each html pages

Tags: html, master-pages, dhtml

I have some ten html pages each page also has same header and footer tag can i have one page with complete header and footer ,and i will refer to that particular page from other html pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do this by using a server side language like [PHP](http://php.net) or another one of the myriad different languages out there, which pre-processes the page. Something along these lines:

```
<?php include 'header.html'; ?>

... page contents...

<?php include 'footer.html'; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , is their any way to do on the clientside without using any serverside controls.

Comment: @mahesh I guess you *could* do it in Javascript if you're so inclined (fetch header and footer files via AJAX, inject into DOM), but I really wouldn't recommend it. You'll also still have to repeat a certain amount of HTML preamble this way anyway.

Comment: I am using asmx webservices on the serverside .

Comment: You can do this using XSLT on the client. All modern browsers have decent XLST support, including IE6. :)

Comment: Is thier any way of using contentplaceholder like control which is used in asp.net for html pages

Answer (score 6):

If you don't care about users who have JavaScript disabled, or are using some mobile platforms, you can use JavaScript to do it.

**headerfooter.js**

```
window.onload = function ()
    {
        var header = document.getElementById('header');
        var footer = document.getElementByID('footer');

        header.innerHTML = "<h1>My website</h1><h2>Rules</h2>";
        footer.innerHTML = "<small>This code is in the public domain</small>";
    }
```

**page.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="headerfooter.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    ... Your content ...
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But don't do this, it's user unfriendly, and unprofessional. Just stick with either using php, or building a solid template which doesn't need to be edited much later.

Comment: Ya can i do with template building

Answer (score 1):

What's your server side scripting language? You can do what is called an "include."

The exact syntax depends on the language(s) your web server supports.

Comment: I am using webservices on serverside with c# coding,I want my html to be plain without using any asp tags into it is thier any way to do it on the clientside

Comment: Yes, with XSL include. I have to say it's probably better to do it server side because you know for certain it will get included going to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the "master-pages" tag on the question refers to ASP.NET, here's a [Super Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx).
Ps. You should give [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) a try as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). The best thing out there when you get a hang of it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Absolutely** we can **Avoid Writing same code** like header and footer on multiple pages by having **just a single header and footer content** defined and use it on all pages.

Lets assume you have header and footer elements in your index.html for example as shown below:

```
<header id='header'>
<!-- Code-->
</header>

<!---Body contents -->

<footer id='footer'>
<!-- Some code-->
</footer>
```

Use JavaScript to store header and footer contents in a variable

```
<script>
var header_content = '<!-- Code for header---> ;
var footer_content = '<!-- Code for footer---> ;

var header_element = document.getElementById('header');
var footer_element = document.getElementById('footer');

header_element.innerHTML = header_content;
footer_element.innerHTML = footer_content;
</script>
```

Use this script on pages you would like to add header and footer and enjoy the power of JavaScript.

> Code Duplication must be minimum in our document as it increases
> redundancy(Extra content not actually needed)/size of document + its
> really unprofessional to have same code repeated over and over again.

We can discuss this topic of **Code Duplication** in much greater depth with lots of cons(Disadvantages) and Less pros(Advantages).

**JavaScript is the best solution** because **no server-side scripting needed**, only Client side scripting and yeah for this to work, your client side browsers must have **JavaScript Enabled** that's default for major browsers nowadays.