# HTML inherit page layout

Tags: html, master-pages

Is it possible to have a regular html page inherit its layout from another html page? If so, what is the most advisable approach for doing this?
I know that aspx uses .master pages to hold the elements common to all pages in the site.

Comment: Can you not just use a CSS file?

Comment: Are you referring to they layout of the page content, or to some content which acts as a template for the pages on your site?

Comment: I meant as a template for for the other pages in the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could fetch resources using JS and AJAX if you absolutely cannot use a serverside language.

[how can we avoid header and footer code repeating in each html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809669/how-can-we-avoid-header-and-footer-code-repeating-in-each-html-pages)

Jekyll works too:
[What is the best way to manage duplicate code in static HTML websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088198/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-duplicate-code-in-static-html-websites/1088236#1088236)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use get variables and php functions to create and display the content dynamically and avoid using more that one HTML